# When using IndexedDB, how can I delete multiple records using an index that is not the key?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I have code to create an indexedDB here:

```
function create_db() {
    var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
    var request = indexedDB.open(“photos”, 2);

    request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
        var db = event.target.result;

        // Create photo db
        var photo_store = db.createObjectStore("photos", {keyPath: "photo_id"});
        var photo_id_index = photo_store.createIndex("by_photo_id",        "photo_id", {unique: true});
        var dest_id_index  = photo_store.createIndex("by_destination_id",  "destination_id");

        console.log(“store created”);
    };

    request.onsuccess = function(event) {
        console.log(“store opened”);
    };

    request.onerror = function(event) {
        console.log("error: " + event);
    };
```

}

My code to remove entries:

```
 function remove_photos = function (destination_id, db) {
var transaction = db.transaction("photos", "readwrite");
var store       = transaction.objectStore("photos");
var index       = store.index("by_destination_id");
var request     = index.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.only(destination_id));

request.onsuccess = function() {
    var cursor = request.result;

    if (cursor) {
        cursor.delete();
        cursor.continue();
    }
};
```

}

How can I delete records using the by_destination_id index so that I can delete all records with a given destination_id, which is an integer?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to my issue, the IDBKeyRange.only function doesn't like integers it needs to be a string, so substituting this line in:

```
var request = index.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.only(destination_id.toString()));
```

Make the code work.

Comment: alec, accept your answer if completely answers your question

Comment: @DeniSpasovski, will do as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: You do have more than 15 reputation so you can do it now!

Comment: @DeniSpasovski It still says I have to wait an hour, so I'll accept it as soon as I can.